# How to delete multiple rows in php using checkbox?

Tags: php, checkbox, delete-row

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" style="display:inline"  method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="del" value="Delete">

    <br>

    <?php

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root") OR DIE ("cant connect to server".mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db("bedanshare") OR DIE ("cannot select db".mysql_error());

    $stud=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentreg");

    $count=mysql_num_rows($stud);

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<th><center />#</th>"; 
    echo "<th><center />Student Number</th>";
    echo "<th><center />First Name</th>";
    echo "<th><center />Last Name</th>";
    echo "<th><center />E-mail</th>";
    echo "<th><center />Username</th>";
    echo "<th><center />Password</th>"; 

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($stud))
    {
    echo "<tr>";?>
    <td><input name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' id='checkbox[]' value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
    <?php
    echo "<td><center />".$row['ID']."</td>";
    echo "<td><center />".$row['Fname']."</td>";
    echo "<td><center />".$row['Lname']."</td>";
    echo "<td><center />".$row['EmailAddress']."</td>";
    echo "<td><center />".$row['Username']."</td>";
    echo "<td><center />".$row['Password']."</td>";  
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    if($del)
    {
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
    $id=$checkbox[$i];
    $dels=mysql_query("DELETE FROM studentreg WHERE ID='$id'");
    }

    }

    ?>

    </form>
```

how come the code doesnt delete rows? :( help please. no data seem to be affected. ID is my primary key, however when I click delete, nothing happens. i dont think my query is wrong. btw im using checkboxes to delete multiple rows.

Comment: **1.** `mysql_` functions are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com). Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions instead. **2.** Your script is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 2):

There's a condition:

```
if($del)
```

Only if it's true it will enter the loop and will start deleting rows.
The problem is that the variable `$del` is not defined in your code.

**Edit:** 
Change your condition to:

```
if(array_key_exists('del',$_POST))
```

and change the next line as well, from:

```
$id=$checkbox[$i];
```

to:

```
$id=$_POST['checkbox'][$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code there is two bugs.
1. $del is undefined variable.
2. $checkbox[] is undefined variable.

You have to modify above code as shown below:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))   // Not if($del)
$id = $_POST['checkbox'][$i]; // Not $id=$checkbox[$i];
```